# TypeError: Unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray' in keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, hash, artificial-intelligence

I have a code below

```
while True:
   
    question = input("你： ")


    question_seq = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences([question])
    
    question_seq_padded = keras.preprocessing.sequence.pad_sequences(question_seq, maxlen=max_len)
    
    answer_seq = model.predict(question_seq_padded).argmax(axis=-1)[0]
    answer = tokenizer.index_word[answer_seq]
    print("機器人：", answer)
```

And when i ran it, happened some wrong

```
answer = tokenizer.index_word[answer_seq]
```

issued error

```
TypeError: Unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
```

I try to find the wrong, maybe answer_seq can't hash, I don't know.

Comment: Did you try to check the result that you get from `answer_seq = model.predict(question_seq_padded).argmax(axis=-1)[0]`? Is it correct? What do you think the result should look like? In particular, what should the *type* be? Aside from that, please read [ask] and [mre]. Make sure that someone else can **copy and paste** the code **without adding or changing anything** to see the **exact problem, directly**.

Comment: @Ake I used your code but IDE give me a error 'KeyError: (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)'I don't know, maybe tokenizer.index_word want the integer not the tuple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the way to fix the code, just add something like below.

```
    answer_seq_tuple = tuple(answer_seq)
    answer = tokenizer.sequences_to_texts(answer_seq_tuple)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use tokenizer.sequences_to_texts([answer_seq]) instead.